# C# WPF Select in DataGrid the first row with pressing Enter from a Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, keydown

I have a TextBox (SearchBox - TabIndex=0) and a populated DataGrid TabIndex=1.
I want after input of the keyword in the SearchBox by pressing Enter to select the first row in the DataGrid.

So far i have just this:

```
  private void txtSearchBox_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Enter)
        {
            System.Windows.Controls.TextBox txtb = sender as System.Windows.Controls.TextBox;
            txtb.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
        }
    }
```

It selects the whole DataGrid and not the row.

Thank you for your help.

EDIT:
I´ve added this to code above and the problem was solved :-)

```
dataGrid.SelectedItem = dataGrid.Items[0];
```

Comment: Please write an answer or delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve added the following code to the Searchbox_KeyDown

```
dataGrid.SelectedItem = dataGrid.Items[0];
```

And this solved my problem!